# Synchronization of tables from DB2 to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I had build a T-SQL, that which will sync the tables from DB2 to SQL.We can run the job for every 15 min to sync tables. This query will fetch only the changes that were made from the last job done. But this is the query that which was applicable when the servers are linked. But I don't know, for some reasons my manager want it to be done by SSIS. How can i reach my requirement of syncing data only by fetching the changes from last job done? Is there anyway to modify my query and run it in execute SQL task in SSIS?

```
BEGIN
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ELIG_TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ELIG_TEMP
UPDATE OPENQUERY ([DB2], 'select h_last_job_end from ISO21.V_LATEST_JOB_CYCLE where C_job = ''ELIG''') 
SET h_last_job_end = current_timestamp;

select * into  #ELIG_TEMP from OPENQUERY([DB2],
'Select * from ISO21.V_USR_ELIG p
where I_USR in (select secid from natb.pyratab p,
ISO21.V_LATEST_JOB_CYCLE  pr
where datetime <= h_last_job_end 
and datetime > h_cur_job_start
and c_job = ''ELIG'')')
MERGE iso21.USR_ELIG 
USING #ELIG_TEMP AS ELIG_TEMP
ON (USR_ELIG.I_USR = ELIG_TEMP.I_USR AND USR_ELIG.C_UNIV_TYP = ELIG_TEMP.C_UNIV_TYP AND USR_ELIG.C_UNIV = ELIG_TEMP.C_UNIV)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET USR_ELIG.C_UNIV_TYP = ELIG_TEMP.C_UNIV_TYP,
USR_ELIG.C_UNIV = ELIG_TEMP.C_UNIV                                         

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (I_USR,C_UNIV_TYP,C_UNIV)
VALUES (ELIG_TEMP.I_USR,ELIG_TEMP.C_UNIV_TYP,ELIG_TEMP.C_UNIV)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE;

UPDATE OPENQUERY ([DB2], 'select h_cur_job_start,h_last_job_end from ISO21.V_LATEST_JOB_CYCLE where C_job = ''ELIG''') 
SET h_cur_job_start = h_last_job_end;
END`
```

Comment: SSIS allows you to create an ETL packing and having a T-SQL in there. It's sneaky! Otherwise, I don't know whether SSIS allows you to create a connection to DB2 (maybe it does?). Which of the three servers tagged are you on?

Comment: What is this code -- a stored procedure?  I see the BEGIN and the END but no context.  Also what is up with the TOTAL LACK of indentation?

Comment: I'd say you have to buckle down and read some documentation on SSIS.  There is nothing about SSIS that stops you from implementing this functionality.

Comment: I am using SQL 2014, I know this will be done in SSIS definitely I am successful with the db2 connection manager also. I know how to do. all that I am concern about the modification of code. How to eliminate openquery and   modify the code accordingly